# xargs to execute nc to check port

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are a list of hosts and port in a text file in the below format

```
host1 10000    
host2 20000
```

I want to parallely execute `nc` to check the port connectivity.

I tried the following command

```
cat host-port.txt | xargs -n 1 -I ^ -P 5 nc -w 1 -zv ^ |& grep -v succeeded`
```

but the `nc` command fails with the help message as below

> This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
>   in the netcat-traditional package.
>   usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
>         [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
>         [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]`

If I copy the string from the file and execute it, it works fine. Not sure what happens when `xargs` extracts the line ("host port") and pass it to `nc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
cat hosts.txt| xargs -n 2 sh -c 'nc -w 1 -zv $1 $2' argv0
```

of this script

```
#!/bin/bash
input=hosts.txt
while IFS=' ' read -r host port
do
    echo ${host} ${port}
    # nc -w 1 -zv ${host} ${port} 
done < "$input"
```

Just replace the line `echo ${host} ${port}` with your `nc` options